# How many days will it take to complete the work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A husband and wife, started painting their house, but husband left
>   painting 5 days before the completion of the work. How many days will
>   it take to complete the work, which the husband alone would have
>   completed in 20 days and wife in 15 days?

To solve this problem, At first I have evaluated the portion of the work done by husband.

Which is: $15 \times \frac{1}{20} =\frac{3}{4}$ as I thought total work is $1$.

Now, work done = time required $\times$ work rate.

Where the wrong, I have done?

now for the wife, she will do the portion of the work, $(1 - \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4})$

and therefore, 
 $$1/4 = time  \times  \frac1{15}$$
then the time is = $\frac{15}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is: $15 \times 120 = \frac{3}{4}$ as I thought total work is 1.

I think this is wrong because they both work together, they do $(\frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{20}) = \frac{7}{60}$ of the whole in a day. So, if husband leaves $5$ days early, work left = $5 \times \frac{7}{60} = \frac{7}{12}$. instead of $\frac{1}{4}$ that you used.

Comment: OMG i didn't count the wife from the begining :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way I like to think about these types of problems. Say the house consists of $300$ "units" to be completed.

Then, the husband can complete $300/20=15$ units a day and the wife can complete $300/15=20$ units per day.

Together they can complete $35$ units per day, so the husband left when there were $35\times5=175$ units left. So it will take the wife $175/20=35/4$ days to finish the work.

Comment: I would think that, if the husband left 5 days before completion, the amount of work done after he left was 100, not 175, because only the wife was working.  So the work they did together was 300-100=200, done in $\frac{200 \mathrm{units}}{35 \mathrm{units/day}} = \frac{40}{7}$ days, and the total time taken in completing the work is $\frac{40}{7}+5=\frac{75}{7}$.

Comment: I take the problem statement "5 days before completion" to mean that the husband left 5 days before he AND the wife, working together, would have completed it.

Comment: I realize you took it that way, but it's not the plain meaning of "before completion".  You'd have to say "before planned completion" or some such.  It may very well be that your answer is what the poser had in mind, but if so I'd call the problem statement misleading.

Comment: I agree that the wording "5 days before completion" could be very misleading.